# Add items to a setterless collection property while instantiating a class in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, collections, instantiation

Suppose you have a class with a collection property that does not include a setter.

Is it possible to add items to this collection property while you are instantiating the class?

Basically, I'm trying to find an alternative syntax to accomplishing the following in one line:

```
dim someClass = New SomeClass() With
{
  .SomePropertyWithoutASetter = New List(Of int) From
  {
    1,
    2,
    3
  }
}
```

Of course, you can't do the above because there's no setter - you can only add stuff to someClass.SomePropertyWIthoutASetter by doing:

```
someClass.SomePropertyWIthoutASetter.Add(4);
```

However, I really need to be able to do it all on one line (don't ask why - long story).  Is this actually possible?

Comment: Why don't you just do `Dim someClass As New SomeClass()` and `someClass.SomePropertyWithoutASetter.AddRange({1,2,3})`? You really don't **have to** use a constructor initializer.

Comment: Because I'm not actually doing this in Visual Studio - I'm using a tool that lets you enter a single expression in VB.  I know it's stupid - that's why I said "don't ask why".  :>

Comment: You would like the setter to be at least *Protected* so only the members of your class can call it.  That's not a problem, VB.NET supports that syntax.  You only have to spell it out.

Comment: It is actually good information to have, so we know you are really bound (by a 3rd party tool) to provide a single expression. But maybe also ask them, who created that tool how to accomplish this (after all it is them who created that tool).

Answer (score 0):

Add it in the constructor.

```
Dim someclass As New SomeClass(4)
```

Custom Class:

```
Public Class SomeClass
  Private ints As New List(Of Integer)
  Sub New(int As Integer)
    ints.Add(int)
  End Sub
...
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I can't because it's a third-party class.  :(

Comment: Is the property/field a public one?

Comment: Yep.  It just doesn't have a setter.

Comment: So it's a `ReadOnly` property. Then no.

Answer (score 0):

If the class that you have is inheritable then try the following

```
Public Class NewClassName
    Inherits SomeClass

    Sub New(ByVal Value As Integer)
        MyBase.SomePropertyWIthoutASetter.Add(Value)
    End Sub

End Class
```

this new class will expose all the methods, properties etc of the class that it's inheriting from and will also have a constructor based on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately, they've sealed the class.  :(